# Menu with mouseenter, mouseleave and click to stay open an close

Tags: menu, click, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have this menu who is working with mouseenter/mouseleave and when clicked the item will stay open, if I click in the body, the item it will be closed and when a click in another item it will be opened. The problem is: i want to close the item open when i click him, but with this code i can't do it. I just try toggle and many others things but i can't achieve what i wanted.

```
function handler() {
$('#menu > li').on('mouseenter',function(){
    //mouseenter handler
});    
$('#menu > li').on('mouseleave',function(){
    //mouseleave handler
});}

$('#nav-outer').on('mouseenter mouseleave', handler);


$('#menu > li').on('click', function( e ) {
  e.stopPropagation();
       $('#menu > li').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
       $('#nav-outer').off('mouseenter mouseleave', handler);
        $('#overlay').show();
       });

$('body').click(function(){
  $('#overlay').hide();
  $('#nav-outer').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', handler);
  $('#menu > li').find //etc. like mouseleave handler
  $('#menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){ //etc. like mouseenter handler

});
});
});
```